# Internet Explorer 9. Bootstrap menu not collapsing

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am have nearly finished building a website with the twitter bootstrap framework when I started to test it on other browsers. It's looks and feels great on all browsers (If I may say so myself...) however, on IE9 and probably IE8, etc all fail to collapse the menu bar to expose the subcategories. What could be the cause of this and what could I do to fix it? Is it possible that this is being caused with JavaScript?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Please note that I have looked at similar questions within stack overflow, but they were mostly inconclusive.

```
<!-- Required Parralax JavaScript -->
< script type = "text/javascript"
src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" > < /script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js / jquery.stellar.min.js "></script>
<script type="text / javascript " src="js / waypoints.js "></script>
<script type="text / javascript " src="js / jquery.easing.1.3.js "></script>
<script type="text / javascript " src="js / main.js "></script>
<script src="js / bootstrap.js "></script> 
<!-- Required Styles for theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet " href="http: //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
< link rel = "stylesheet"type = "text/css"href = "css/bootstrap.css" > 
< link rel = "stylesheet"type = "text/css"href = "css/style.css" >
< /head>
<body>
   <header>
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-collapse">
               <span class="icon-bar"></span > < span class = "icon-bar" > < /span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span > < /button>
               <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/logo.png "></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Category: Header-->
            <div class="
               navbar - collapse collapse ">
               <ul class="
                  menu nav navbar - nav pull - right ">
               <li class="
                  dropdown ">
                  <a href="#
                     " class="
                     dropdown - toggle hover1 " data-toggle="
                     dropdown ">Category<b class="
                     caret "></b></a>
                  <ul class="
                     dropdown - menu ">
                     <li><a href="#
                        ">Sub1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#
                        ">Sub 2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#
                        ">Sub 3</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <!-- Category: Header -->
               <li class="
                  dropdown ">
                  <a href="#
                     " class="
                     dropdown - toggle hover1 " data-toggle="
                     dropdown ">Category<b class="
                     caret "></b></a>
                  <ul class="
                     dropdown - menu ">
                     <li><a href="#
                        ">Sub Cat</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#
                        ">Sub Cat</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </header>
```

Comment: did you see any errors in console? F12 > start debugging under console?

Comment: No, but thank you for your suggestion. What this actually turned out to be was IE's default security settings. If you change them to always allow ActiveX and javascript then this problem should be eradicated. Stumbled upon this by complete chance. Hope this helps anybody else out there with the same problem

Comment: If you found solution for your issue, you can answer your own question.

Comment: Unfortunately StackOverflow won't let me answer for another 6 hours due to my low reputation. I will update it then unless someone answers it before me without reading this.

Comment: I up voted the question, perhaps you can post your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

What this actually turned out to be was IE 9's default security settings. If you change them to always allow ActiveX and javascript then this problem should be eradicated. Stumbled upon this by complete chance.

Hope this helps anybody else out there with the same problem